# Java - Get list of file names in the current JAR

Tags: java, jar, zip, iteration, directory

I need to get the file names of each file that is in a particular folder inside my program's JAR while it is running. Is it possible to do this? I'm not sure where to start.

It needs to be done programmatically and be platform independent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To list the contents of a jar file, simply run:

```
$jar tf MyJar.jar
```

Are you looking to do this programmatically from within java?

To do it programmatically, see [this](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/22124) example.

Comment: Yes. I need to do it programmatically and platform independent.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Wild: could you edit your question to include these details?

Comment: Your example seems to do the job.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for something that isn't available in general.  Classes are loaded via `ClassLoader` instances, which may get class bytecode from many different places (network, jar file, .class files in a directory, dynamically generated).

The most you can know is the package hierarchy, which you can get from

```
myObject.getClass().getClassLoader().getPackages()
```

which returns a list of packages available at the point of invocation. For a given package you probably won't be able to tell where it came from.